# Java JMX/RMI produces lots of garbage

Tags: java, garbage-collection, rmi, jmx, jconsole

Using JMX and RMI for monitoring and management of VMs seems to be the cause of a lot of allocation and as a result GC. It mostly seems to allocate char and byte arrays for what I am guessing is serialization. Is there anyway to tune or completely avoid this? The application itself generates almost no garbage hence we could run without GC for days if it wasn't for this. Making the heap huge is not an option. Allocating a massive eden space is not an option.

JMX integrates nicely with our companies monitoring solution hence changing it to something else would require a lot of reconfiguration and potentially custom integration work with our monitoring solution.

Comment: increase polling intervals? "[...] is not an option" ... well, you could also look for other monitoring solutions (depending on what you actually need to monitor)?

Comment: I think you mean decreasing polling intervals right? Increasing polling intervals would just cause more allocation?
The good thing about JMX is that it integrates well with the monitoring solution we have in the company and we already have a lot of pre-configured checks that are used for all services hence changing the monitoring solution would require quite a lot of work.
We are monitoring things like general health and VM stats along with a number of stats exposed via beans.

Comment: you could also paste GC logs to compare JMX vs. non-JMX problems, maybe it can be alleviated with some GC tuning.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: @the8472 if I disable JMX I don't generate any GC. If I enable it I have GC pauses every 5-10 minutes if I leave JConsole connected.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen are you asking why GC is a problem? It is a problem because I need to guarantee consistent latency and it is a low latency application and as such any GC pauses are not ideal.
I could decrease the size of the eden space to amortize the cost of GC and have more GC but I was more looking for a solution to use JMX and avoid the garbage being created.

Comment: @Dasch I am not saying it is not a problem, just asking why, because context is important.  If you have real-time-guarantee issues - which I have not seen any JMX documentation mention they have considered - you essentially cannot rely on code outside your control.  I am not aware of any such options.  Perhaps you could have a companion JVM doing the JMX stuff which talks to your current JVM using a protocol you control?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen sure, context definitely matters and I agree, it is nowhere in the JMX documentation, but I was hoping someone might had a similar issue before and perhaps implemented an alternative transport protocol for JMX which produces less garbage. I guess most other people do what you suggest and have a companion VM which provides the JMX interface and expose the values through their own protocol. I would prefer not having to do that as you get so much out of the box with JMX. It might be my only option though.

Comment: I have previously used Cajo for a scenario where a program HAD to be invoked on a server, so I split it in an invocation part running on the server, and the actual meat in an application running locally inside a full IDE (while developing), and used Cajo to easily do the remote procedure call. It might be useful to you too.  Unfortunately the author died but I have picked it up on https://github.com/ravn/cajo.  Consider it maintained software.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. I had a quick look through the code and it looks like that will do a lot of allocation as well? Have you done any profiling on it?
If I end up with such an architecture I will probably use a non-allocating protocal via IPC (e.g. using Chronicle Map or Aeron with SBE).

Comment: @Dasch I have not used it in any scenario where that was a problem.  It was just a thought that it might be useful to see how hard it would be to actually get a prototype running.

Comment: @Dasch also if it can be refactored to fulfill your needs it might be a worthy improvement?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'll most likely use either Aeron or Chronicle for this solution as we use that already and I also don't think it would be worth the effort as most people don't require no GC, but thanks for the suggestion.